# Unpacking and repacking boot.img changes it's file size

Tags: boot, rom

So I unpacked boot.img file using unpackbootimg in ubuntu. Then without changing the file I repacked it. But the filesize became smaller. From 36.7 MB to 17 MB. I tried to flash that image to my phone. But it failed. Also ramdisk file was empty after unpacking the boot.img.

Note: This specific rom is a rom from Symphony i97. It has Spreadtrum UNISOC SC9863 chipset. And I unpacked this rom using spd research tool. Also this phone's fastboot and adb commands are tempered so most of the commands don't work. Most of the time it says unknown command or not implemented.

Comment: Ubuntu's package is outdated. Use [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) or [magiskboot](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskboot).

Comment: Actually I already used AIK. While using AIK I got an error message saying "The system cannot find the batch label specified". So it seems that this boot.img isn't a normal one. So is there any way to manually decompress the file and extract file data?

Comment: That error indicates a problem with your `.bat` file, not the boot.img. The batch file you downloaded with AIK couldn't run. Check that file (unpackimg.bat) for errors or you may also use AIK on Linux and Android.

Comment: okay. So after reading magisk notes. I think I know why there was no ramdisk. But the problem is even though I patched my recovery image using magisk it won't flash. And yes file size still became small. From 40 MB to 25 MB

Comment: Please explain ***it won't flash***. Size may get smaller, contents should be complete. Which device you are on? Is it A/B, system-as-root, treble? Android version? What's the purpose of unpacking boot.img?

Comment: It's symphony i97. It's a new phone with new Speadtrum Unisoc SC9863 chipset, Android version 9.0, reason for unpacking is for rooting the phone and adding a custom recovery. Tried flashing using spd research tool. Because fastboot won't listen to the commands given.

Comment: No experience with SPD, so can't say anything for sure. Better add that device related info to question.